# fail2ban and iptables rules flood (resulting in poor bandwidth)

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall, fail2ban

I've noticed this pattern happening a few times on my server in the last 6 months:

- First, `fail2ban` detects many SSH attempts from bots, and sucessfully bans them. Indeed in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` I have:

  ```
  [ssh]
  enabled  = true
  port     = ssh
  filter   = sshd
  logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
  maxretry = 3
  findtime = 86400
  bantime = 2678400
  ```
- Then, as a result, `iptables` has *many many* rules, in my case I had **~ 4000 rules** like this:

  ```
  -D fail2ban-ssh -s 1.2.3.4/32 -j DROP
  -D fail2ban-ssh -s 5.6.7.8/32 -j DROP
  ...
  ```
- Finally, the whole internet connection of this server is *very slow* (I noticed only ~ 160 KB/sec bandwidth while downloading a file to my local computer with SFTP), probably because of all these rules.

This solves it temporarily:

```
iptables -S |grep DROP| sed 's/-A/-D/' >rules
cat rules | while read line; do iptables $line; done
iptables -S |wc -l     # ~100 rules (instead of ~4000), good, back to normal!
```

A few seconds after doing this, my bandwidth to local computer is back to normal, i.e. more than 5 MB/sec, which is ok.

But it will happen again in a few weeks, since it has already happened a few times.

**How to avoid this long term issue?**

Comment: You could reduce the bantime.  That would result in fewer sources being banned.

Comment: Thank you @Stewart, but shouldn't these bots (who have attempted to login via SSH and hack my server) be banned forever?

Comment: @Stewart if I reduce the bantime by editing `jail.conf`, should I do something to reload the rules? Do you remember which command it is?

Comment: Probably `systemctl restart fail2ban`

Answer (score 2):

`ipset` was designed to solve this problem. You can create a set of IPs or subnets:

```
ipset create bannedv4 hash:net family ipv4 comment
ipset create bannedv6 hash:net family ipv6 comment
```

Add a single iptables rule like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set bannedv4 src -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -m set --match-set bannedv6 src -j DROP
```

Then you can add many entries to the banned sets. I'm not sure how to configure fail2ban to use it. For me there are already ipset actions defined in `/etc/fail2ban/action.d` but it's probably distro specific.

```
ipset add bannedv4 1.2.3.4/16 comment "SSH bot"
ipset add bannedv6 64:ff9b::1.2.3.4/112 comment "SSH bot"
```

It is also possible to have expiring entries. When you create the set, simply add the `timeout 604800` option to only ban them for a week. You can override this default timeout by passing the same option to `ipset add`. You will probably also want to save the sets from your init scripts, like you save your iptables rules. Note that you have to restore the sets before the iptables rules.

```
ipset save > /var/lib/firewall/ipset
ipset restore < /var/lib/firewall/ipset
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which distro do you use? (I might be using the same). Also, how is `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` configured to make use of `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/`'s `ipset` rules? I'll probably try to use it as well.

Comment: I have Devuan but I don't normally use fail2ban on my machines, just installed it now to check it out. So I don't have a good config for it.

Answer (score 0):

As already correctly said `ipset` is better suitable for huge lists.
This is possible configuration (fail2ban >= v.0.10) in your `jail.local` to specify default action for all jails:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
banaction_allports = iptables-ipset-proto6-allports
```

As regards the `bantime` 2678400 (31 days?!) - such long ban directly after 3 failures only is a bit too heavy, and at least not recomended.
If you have fail2ban v.0.11, you can use incremental bantime feature - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66443690/7161854 for example.